# *** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse) in haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, io

I'm trying to write a program that loops all the time waiting for an input from the user but for some reason it doesn't loop.
My program is :

```
charAt :: String->Char->Int
main = do 
    x <- readLn
    if x == 1
        then do
           putStrLn "Word: "
           word <- getLine
           putStrLn "Char: "
           ch <- getChar
           putStrLn (show (charAt word ch))
        else print "Nothing"
    main
```

But i actually get this error:

> *** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)

If i remove the last main calling the program will work .
does anybody knows why is that happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `getChar`, it will take only a single character from your stream. However, if you've entered <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, the newline character `'\n'` is still in your `stdin`. A `'\n'` cannot get parsed into an `Int`, therefore you end up with that error.

You can remove that newline if you call `getLine` afterwards:

```
       ch <- getChar
       putStrLn (show (charAt word ch))
       _ <- getLine
```

Or you write your own helpers:

```
promptInt :: IO Int
promptInt = do
  putStr "Int: "
  line <- getLine
  case readMaybe line of
    Just x -> return x
    _      -> putStrLn "Try again." >> promptInt

promptChar :: IO Char
promptChar = do
  putStr "Char: "
  line <- getLine
  case line of
    [x,_] -> return x
    _     -> putStrLn "Try again." >> promptChar
```